# How to open/run YML compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

How can I open/run a YML compose file on my computer? I've installed Docker for Windows and Docker tools but couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To manage `.yml` files you have to install and use Docker Compose.

Installation instructions can be found here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

After the installation, go to your `docker-compose.yml` directory and then execute `docker-compose up` to create and start services in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

If you need more information, take a look to Docker Compose docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose

Comment: Docker for windows includes compose, from docs: Docker for Mac, Docker for Windows, and Docker Toolbox include Docker Compose, so most Mac and Windows users do not need to install Docker Compose separately.

Answer (score 72):

If you are asking how to open YAML files, then you can use some common editors like [NotePad++](https://community.home-assistant.io/t/tips-for-editing-yaml-with-notepad/4295) in windows or vim in linux. 
If your question is about running the compose yaml file, then run this command from the directory where compose file is residing:

```
docker-compose -f {compose file name} up
```

You can avoid `-f` if your filename is `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: Hum... it is "locked", need the "&" to only run-and-go?  So `docker-compose   up &`

Comment: How to KILL??   After `docker stop`  the composed, they stay there!

Comment: @PeterKrauss for a stack started with `docker-compose up`, use `docker-compose stop` to just stop the containers, or `docker-compose down` to stop and remove them.

Comment: if you used `docker-compose .. up &` use fg to focus on the process and then stop it as ctrl+c

Although, I think this is not good way to run docker-compose on background. For this purpose you should use flag -d -> `docker-compose .. up -d`


-d, --detach               Detached mode: Run containers in the background,
                               print new container names. Incompatible with
                               --abort-on-container-exit.